# How do you use the latest version (0.8.1.2 at time of writing) of the iteratee library?

Tags: haskell, loops

I've read tutorials on the iteratee and enumerator concepts, and have implemented a sample version as a way of learning how they work. However, the types used in the iteratee package are very different than any of the tutorials I have found. For example, `Iteratee` is defined as:

```
Iteratee     
   runIter :: forall r. (a -> Stream s -> m r) 
           -> ((Stream s -> Iteratee s m a) 
           -> Maybe SomeException -> m r) 
           -> m r
```

I really don't understand what I am meant to do with that. Are there any tutorials on using this version, and why it was written this way (ie what benefits this has over the original way Oleg did it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the current maintainer of iteratee.

You may find some of the files in the iteratee [Examples](http://tiresiaspress.us/haskell/iteratee/Examples/) directory useful for understanding how to use the library; [word.hs](http://tiresiaspress.us/haskell/iteratee/Examples/word.hs) is probably the easiest to follow.

Basically, users shouldn't need to use `runIter` unless you're creating custom enumeratees.  Iteratees can be created by combining the provided primitives, and also with the `liftI`, `idone`, and `icont` functions, enumerated over, and then run with `run` or `tryRun`.

Oleg has two "original" versions and a CPS version (and possibly others too).  The original versions are both in http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/Iteratee/IterateeM.hs.  The first is the actual code, and the second is in the comments.  The first requires some special functions, `>>==` and `$$`, in place of the usual `>>=` and `$`.  The second can use the standard functions, but unfortunately it's very difficult to reason about monadic ordering with this version.  There are a few other drawbacks as well.  The CPS version avoids all of these issues, which is why I switched over iteratee.  I also find that iteratees defined in this style are shorter and more readable.  Unfortunately I'm not aware of any tutorials specific to the CPS version, however [Oleg's comments](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/Iteratee/IterateeMCPS.hs) may be useful.

Comment: Thanks, the example programs and Oleg's comments on IteratorMCPS.hs are very useful, especially when no tutorial exists on this library.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I don't know the iteratee much and have never used them. So take my answer
with a grain of salt.

This definition is equivalent to Oleg's (more precisely, it's
a CPS-style sum), with a twist: it guarantees that accessing the
iteratee always return a monadic value.

Here is Oleg definition:

```
 data Iteratee el m a =
   | IE_done a
   | IE_cont (Maybe ErrMsg)
             (Stream el -> m (Iteratee el m a, Stream el))
```

So it's a sum of either `done a`, we're done a give `a` as a result,
or `cont (Maybe ErrMsg) (Stream el -> ...)` : a way to continue the
iteration given another chunk of input and, possibly an error (in
which case continuing the continuation amounts to restarting the
computation).

It is well-known that `Either a b` is equivalent to `forall r. (a ->
r) -> (b -> r) -> r` : giving you either `a` or `b` is equivalent to
promising you that, for any result `r` transform on `a` and transform
of `b` you may come up with, I will be able to produce such an `r` (to
do that I must have a `a` or a `b`). In a sense, (Either a b)
*introduces* a data, and `r. (a -> r) -> (b -> r) -> r` *eliminates*
this data: if such a function was named `case_ab`, then `case_ab (\a ->
foo_a) (\b -> foo_b)` is equivalent to the pattern matching `case
ab of { Left a -> foo_a; Right b -> foo_b }` for some `ab :: Either a b`.

So here is the continuation (we talk of continuations here because
`(a -> r)` represents "what will happen of the value once we know it's
an `a`") equivalent of Oleg's definition:

```
data Iteratee el m a =
  forall r.
    (a -> r) ->
    ((Maybe ErrMsg), (Stream el -> m (Iteratee el m a, Stream el)) -> r) ->
     r
```

But there is a twist in the iteratee definition (modulo some innocuous
currying): the result is not `r` but `m r`: in a sense, we force the
result of pattern matching on our iteratee to always live in the monad
`m`.

```
data Iteratee el m a =
  forall r.
    (a -> m r) ->
    (Maybe ErrMsg -> (Stream el -> m (Iteratee el m a, Stream el)) -> m r) ->
     m r
```

Finally, notice that the "continuating the iteration" data in Oleg's
definition is `Stream .. -> m (Iterate .., Stream ..)`, while in the
iteratee package it's only `Stream -> Iteratee`. I assume that they
have removed the monad here because they enforce it at the outer level
(if you apply the iteratee, you are forced to live in the monad, so
why also force subsequent computation to live in the monad?). I don't
know why there isn't the `Stream` output anymore, I suppose it means
that those Iteratee have to consume all the input when it is available
(or encode a "not finished yet" logic in the return type `a`). Perhaps
this is for efficiency reasons.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that the relation between `Either a b` and `forall r. (a -> r) -> (b -> r) -> r`. That helps a lot with understanding the library. As experimentation, I made some code at http://hpaste.org/45964/either__rank2_type_correspon that demonstrates that relationship (you can add the code to your post if you want as it demonstrates the relationship pretty well).

Comment: I find the [following code](http://hpaste.org/45971/either__rank2_type_correspon) more enlightening.

Comment: iteratee is based upon a slightly older formulation of Oleg's; he changed it very recently.  In the version iteratee is based upon, the first branch of the definition is `IE_done a (Stream el)`, and an unfinished iteratee must have consumed all available input.  I'm still undecided as to whether to make this change in "iteratee"; I'm not certain it's very beneficial after the CPS transformation, and it would be a big disruption.